# How to prove that a definite integral is lesser or equal to a certain value?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have to show that $$\int_1^\sqrt{3} {\sin x\over e^x(x^2+1)}\le {\pi\over 12e}$$

First step I did is observe that the function inside the integral (=:f) is continuous, and thus we can write $$F(x):= \int_1^x {\sin x\over e^x(x^2+1)}$$

where $F'(x) = f(x)$

Then, since $f(x)\le {1\over 2e}$ for all $x\in [1,\sqrt{3}]$ , the Mean Value Theorem shows that $F(\sqrt{3})-F(1)=F(\sqrt{3})\le {\sqrt{3}-1\over 2e}$
but this is not quite enough as it is bigger than $\pi\over 12e$.

I also tried to derivate f to find the local maximum and be able to state that f is smaller than something $\lt {1\over 2e}$, but it is hard to solve so I doubt this is the way to go because it is not really the point of the section of the course we are in (section is Fundamental Theorem of Calculus). Also, obtaining the expression $1\over 2e$ hints that I am in the right way since if I would be able to multiply this by $\pi\over 6$ I would arrive at the right answer, but I just don't see how to get it while at the same time having $\int_1^\sqrt{3} {\sin x\over e^x(x^2+1)}\le F(b)-F(a)$ and $b-a={\pi\over 6}$

Would also love to hear about a general strategy to solve this kind of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integrand is positive on the interval of integration.  We have 
$${\sin{x}\over e^x}\leq {1\over e^x}$$
 and since $e^{-x}$ decreases, we have
$$\int_1^\sqrt{3} {\sin x\over e^x(x^2+1)}\leq {1\over e}\int_1^\sqrt{3} {1\over x^2+1} ={1\over e}(\arctan{\sqrt{3}}-\arctan{1})={\pi\over12e}$$

Comment: Should that be $$\int_1^\sqrt{3} {1\over x^2+1}dx \color{red} {=} \arctan{\sqrt{3}}-\arctan{1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that since $e^x$ is an increasing function, hence on the interval $[1,\sqrt{3}]$ , $e^x\ge e$

Hence $$\int_1^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{\sin x}{e^x(x^2+1)}dx\le \int_0^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{\sin x}{e(x^2+1)}dx$$

We also know that $\displaystyle \forall\space x\in\Bbb{R}\space \sin x \le 1$ . Hence 
$$\int_1^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{\sin x}{e(x^2+1)}dx\le \int_1^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{1}{e(x^2+1)}dx=\frac{1}{e}\int_1^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{e}\Bigg[\arctan x\Bigg]_0^{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1}{e}\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{\pi}{12e}$$

Hence $$\int_1^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{\sin x}{e^x(x^2+1)}dx\le\frac{\pi}{12e}$$